# Converting Ruby String with array into array and iterate it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to convert the following string into an array/nested array and iterate through it, so that i could use values from it.

```
 str = "[[{"one": "1"}],[{"two": "2"}],[{"three": "3"}]]"

// I want to use value inside the {} brace
```

Comment: data = JSON.parse(str) // You might need to add the "gem 'json'" to the Gemfile first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is JSON(*), and can be parsed as JSON.

```
require 'json'
data = JSON.parse(str)
```

And then you can use the usual `Array#each` or `Hash#each` iterators.

*) Or at least it would be JSON, if it wasn't a syntax error. You can't have an unescaped double quote inside double quotes.

Comment: Thanks. with that i am getting {"one": "1"} and {"two": "2"} in for each loop. but when in loop i m trying to get ele["one"] or ele["two"] getting error like -  TypeError (can't convert String into Integer):

Comment: Note that each hash in your data is wrapped in another array. The structure is Array of Arrays of Hashes. You would need `ele[0]["one"]` to get to the `"1"`, or onion together two `each` loops (one for the outer Array, one for the inner Array).